# Abrir nova aba usando selenium e python

Tags: python

Já tentei de tudo. É o seguinte. Abro uma página usando `selenium` e a linguagem python, depois tento abrir uma nova guia, para depois ir para essa nova guia, depois fechar esta guia. Só isso. Mas na prática, a página inicial é carregada, as linhas de abrir nova guia (e consequentemente fechá-la) são ignoradas, sem lançar nenhuma exceção, e depois ele prossegue o código normalmente e fecha o navegador, como se eu não tivesse mandado abrir uma nova guia e fechá-la. E se tem erros nesse código de abrir nova guia e fechar, ele deveria lançar exceção, não?

Código:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

# Abre uma nova aba
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') 

# Carrega a nova aba
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

# Fecha a aba
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w') 


driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar isso:

```
# Abre uma nova aba e vai para o site do SO
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank')")

# Muda de aba
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Fecha a aba
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

Comment: Ok. Mas essa solução tem dois problemas 1) Ao menos no meu computador, o programa está fechando a guia atual e deixando a nova guia lá. Pelo que entendi, a guia que o André quer fechar é a nova. 2) Uma questão menor: o método switch_to_window está deprecated, foi substituído por switch_to.window

Comment: Exatamente. Quero ir para a nova guia, e depois fechá-la

Comment: Então, para fazer isso basta trocar driver.window_handles[0] por driver.window_handles[1]. Tenta aí

Comment: Editei o código pra funcionar como você quer. A questão era só alterar o para driver.window_handles[1], já que a primeira aba seria a aba 0.

Comment: Qual erro? Testei aqui e funcionou bem. Tenta dar um import time e dar um tempo entre carregar a nova aba e fechar, com time.sleep(3), por exemplo.

Comment: Está dando erro quando executo o código, está faltando alguma biblioteca? usei as seguintes bibliotecas, talvez mais do que precisasse e o código ficou assim: 

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

# Abre uma nova aba e vai para o site do SO driver.execute_script("window.open('stackoverflow.com', '_blank')") 

# Muda de aba 
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1]) 

# Fecha a aba 
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

Comment: Ele acusa erro nesta linha: 

----> 6 driver.execute_script("window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank')")

Comment: Galera funcionou, me desculpe Guilherme, copiei o seu código, coloquei importei as bibliotecas, mas tinha esquecido de iniciar o navegador. Foi mal, seu código funcionou sim, muito obrigado man!!!

Comment: Sem problemas, André! Que bom que funcionou. Se possível, clica no botão de 'check' ao lado da resposta para marcar como correta. Abraço!

Comment: Está lá clicado brother! Valeuzão

Answer (score 0):

o essa linha de mandar comando no crhome (driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')) num deu certo. mas consegui resolver o problema selecionando a aba com esse (driver.execute_script("window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank')") e pra fechar basta selecionar a aba com (driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])) depois fecha com o driver.close().
tentei mandar um comando de uma linha fechando uma tela específica mas deu certo não. mas resolveu o problema só de selecionar. se num selecionar ele fecha a primeira aba.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.